# How to make complete form in which background color of button changes when user starts typing in input field with javascript , html and css?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, event-handling

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const inputfield = document.getElementById("username");

inputfield.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  const val = e.target.value;
  if (val === "") {
    btn.disabled = true;
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
  } else {
    btn.disabled = false;
    btn.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
  <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Now the issue is that it only works for one input and the associated button field
it does not work for another pair of input field and button , so what changes should i make in the above javascript code in which it runs for as many as input field and button i want?

Please can anyone help me in this. Thank you

If you have full jquery code it's also accepted.

Comment: Are you actually trying to color the button or should the button just be greyed out/ disabled out for invalid/ no input? In that case think about using `pattern` attribute and `disabled`. See [form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: first the button color is grey as soon the user starts typing it should change the color of the button

Comment: Will you have one button for each input or one button for all the inputs?

Comment: each input have one button like field name (1 input 1 button ) another field email ( 1 input 1 button)

Comment: so why do you put one button and input in your question??

Comment: @M.RMRF Because the question is an example of his actual code.

Comment: I said in the question that it does not work for another set of input and button 

Comment: Well you need to use the `class` and `for loop` to apply `keyup eventHandler` to all the inputs.

Comment: @OmkarDhumal so edit your question with another pair of button and input to reproduce your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach was to put the input and button in a div with a custom class.
And just loop over every div, get the child inputs and buttons and just use your existing code for every div.

```js
const btns = document.getElementsByClassName('inputButton');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  let input = btns[i].querySelector('input');
  let button = btns[i].querySelector('button');

  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    const val = e.target.value;
    if (val === "") {
      button.disabled = true;
      button.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    } else {
      button.disabled = false;
      button.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inputButton">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
    <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inputButton">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
    <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="inputButton">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
    <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it into a additional div element and iterate trough. For each "input-group" you can add an event listener to the input child and edit the style of the button child.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.input-group').forEach((group) => {
  let input = group.querySelector('input');
  let button = group.querySelector('button');
  input.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if(input.value !== "") {
      button.disabled = false; 
    } else {
      button.disabled = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#btn[disabled] {
  background: red;
}

#btn {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
    <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
    <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
    <button disabled id="btn" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You saved life man !!!!  Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can make a loop with a class to add an event listener to every input you want.
You can use data-whateverYouWant to link the button to the input
Also, should make your style in css.

```js
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("an-input");
for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    let btn  = document.querySelectorAll("[data-placeholder="+this.placeholder+"]")[0];
    if (this.value === "") {
      btn.disabled = true;
    } else {
      btn.disabled = false;
    }
 })
}
```

```css
button{
  background-color:orange;
}
button:disabled,
button[disabled]{
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<input class="an-input" placeholder="Username" class="input" />
<button disabled data-placeholder="Username" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>

<input class="an-input" placeholder="email" class="input" />
<button disabled data-placeholder="email" type="button" class="button">Submit</button>
```